# Why doesn't fstream work when called from Swift (Xcode)?

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, objective-c++

I'm working on an Xcode project that compares rendering with Metal and OpenGL.

It's separated in 2 different targets so the Metal part is in Swift and the OpenGL part is in C++.

I made a C++ class for model loading for both of them to access. The OpenGL(C++) part accesses it directly and the Metal part has some Objetice-C++ code to bridge with so it works with Swift. The ModelLoader constructor looks something like this:

```cpp
ModelLoader(const char*  modelPath)
{
    fstream modelFileStream(modelPath);
    string line;
    if (modelFileStream.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(modelFileStream, line))
        {
            // obj parsing
        }
        modelFileStream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open model file at path: " << modelPathString << endl;
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I use this directly on the OpenGL (C++) target is works fine, but when I use it in my Metal (Swift) target, it doesn't open the file successfully and prints "Failed to open model file at path: **(path used on argument)**".

I already tried using relative paths (through Edit Scheme > Use custom working directory) and also absolute paths. Both work with the OpenGL version but not on the Metal one. Also tried directly hard coding the path on the ModelLoader constructor and nothing.

The bridging with Objective-C++ also seems to be working fine since it prints the messages. The path printed in both targets is exactly the same, so it's not something done by the bridging.

So what is going on?

Comment: If you use sandbox enabled application target, then you cannot use absolute paths due to sandbox restrictions.

Comment: Disabling sandbox solved it, thank you! Any ideas why it doesn't work even with relative paths though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling "App Sandbox" in the entitlements solved this.